# Why am I getting a little-endian error when importing .so file in python

Tags: python, import

Im attempting to use a C++ extension for Python called PySndObj. and getting an error I have never seen and cannot find anything about on the web :(

ImportError: /home/nhnifong/SndObj-2.6.6/python/_sndobj.so: ELF file data encoding not little-endian

I know that probably means the byte order is backwards, So I tried writing a little script that read the file 2 bytes at a time and switched their order before writing them back out. It didn't work.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: if you are on a 32-bit machine you should take 4 bytes at a time with your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to build the extension from source yourself.

It was valiant of you to try and "reverse the bytes", but only certain sections of the ELF file have word-oriented (as opposed to byte-oriented) data.

Furthermore, it's unlikely that the dll in question was compiled for your system's CPU architecture.